# Where to fix part in moment setup for FEA

Tags: mechanical-engineering, finite-element-method

I'm working on a project that involves supporting a distributed load on a bar that is held up by a moment at one end of a lever arm. My goal is to assess how much the bar bends under the distributed load and how much difference in displacement exists for the actuated and non-actuated lever arms. Here's the setup:

[image: Torque is purely in the x direction and only on the lever arm shown. Distributed load is entirely in the xz plane. Lever arms are pointed in the y direction.]

Having done only limited finite element analysis in school before, I'm not sure how best to add constraints. In reality, both lever arms will be free to rotate and will not transfer the moment load past the pivoting axis, where the dashed line is. I did a quick setup the other day where I fixed the bar, but that was more to get a feel for the software I'm using and gave inaccurate results.

Is there anywhere that can be fixed in this setup? The only place I can think of is the structure that I haven't shown in the drawing, which is what the pivot points interface with.

Comment: Since you mention actuated and non-actuated lever arms, presumably the force and/or moment that restrains this part of the structure actually comes from the "actuator," whatever that is. You probably need to model the actuator and constrain it to be in the correct position (i.e. fix it where it is driven by the motor, or whatever).

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is here, probably as the answer is so obvious to me (put the moment constraint in where there is a moment constraint in reality). Perhaps another image of your attempted FE model would help, so that we could compare the existing diagram with it?

Comment: I guess my confusion came in because I hadn't thought about replacing the moment with a constraint. The only other times I've done this there has also been a fixed point, like a wall joint. That makes complete sense though.

Comment: If you apply a constraint, you get a reaction force at that point. Theoretically, you could apply the correct forces and moments which the actuator would apply (though if the structure is not statically determinate, you might have a hard time calculating them!) and then you would have a structure with self-equilibrating external loads and no constraints at all. Newton's laws of motion say that's not a problem, and the structure won't move, but to analyse a "free body" using FEM you need a special option to handle it, which is solving your problem the hard way!